# Tap to select specific plane in ARCore with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm trying to create a modification to the ARCore sample Andy placement app by only rendering a single plane instead of all the detected planes. I'd like to achieve this by tapping on the plane to be rendered. Here's what I've tried.

```cs
protected override void OnEndManipulation(TapGesture gesture)
{
    if (gesture.WasCancelled)
    {
        return;
    }

    // If gesture is targeting an existing object we are done.
    if (gesture.TargetObject != null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Raycast against the location the player touched to search for planes.
    TrackableHit hit;
    TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinInfinity | TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon;

    if (Frame.Raycast(gesture.StartPosition.x, gesture.StartPosition.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered into hit if condition");
        // Use hit pose and camera pose to check if hittest is from the
        // back of the plane, if it is, no need to create the anchor.
        if ((hit.Trackable is DetectedPlane) &&
            Vector3.Dot(FirstPersonCamera.transform.position - hit.Pose.position,
                hit.Pose.rotation * Vector3.up) < 0)
        {
            //var andyObject = Instantiate(AndyPrefab, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);
            Debug.Log("Hit at back of the current DetectedPlane");
        }
        else
        {                
            if (PlaneFixed is false)
            {
                foreach (GameObject plane in DetectedPlaneGenerator.instance.PLANES) //RK
                {
                    // THE PROBLEM IS HERE! HOW TO GET CORRECT TYPECAST?
                    if (hit.Trackable is plane)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Plane Selected");
                        PlaneFixed = true;
                        FixPositionButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        plane.SetActive(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm unable to get the correct matching between a GameObject (PLANES - created in DetectedPlaneGenerator.cs) and the DetectedPlane object (return by hit.Trackable, using the PlaneWithinInfinity | PlaneWithinPolygon raycastfilters).

I've also seen the method to try and associate a 'tag' to the DetectedPlaneVisualizer ([solution to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254092/disable-toggle-visualization-of-tracked-planes-in-arcore-unity)). However, I see that this too deals with planes using a GameObject. How to match the GameObject and Hit.Trackable (DetectedPlane Object) to identify which specific plane was just tapped on?