# I want to disable the MeshRenderer of DetectedPlanes on a button click. I am using ARCore sample project

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

i am trying to disable the MeshRenderer Component on detected plane using ARCore. I want to disable the MeshRenderer once the object is placed on the plane. I am not very expert in unity. I am using HelloARContoller.cs and DetectedPlaneVisualizer.cs

Comment: What have you tried, and where did it fail?

Comment: Hi Itamar Mushkin. Thanks for your reply. I am just beginner not very good in coding.I tried couple of codes like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254092/disable-toggle-visualization-of-tracked-planes-in-arcore-unity. 

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/176  

But i could not understand what to do. Can you please help me out. I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set game object meshRenderer like this:
In addition, you can use list if you need to store a list for DetectedPlanes. After that, you can iterate and close their meshrenderers via button

```
private void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
   {
       gameObject.renderer.enabled = !gameObject.renderer.enabled;
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi Ugur Tufekci thank you for helping me. Can you please also let me know that script needs to be attached to DetectedPlaneVisualizer or HelloARController. 

I have a ExampleController GameObject to which HelloARController script is attached. 

I tried couple of codes like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254092/disable-toggle-visualization-of-tracked-planes-in-arcore-unity. 

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/176  

But i could not understand what to do. Can you please help me out. I would really appreciate.